# Failing to run simplest spec: TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Options()')

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, brunch, karma-jasmine

[jsfiddle test of the coffeescript class Options](http://jsfiddle.net/kross/n8mE2/) also included here `options.coffee`:

```
class Options
    constructor: () ->

    # public accessible
    defaults:
        lang: "en"
        aspectRatio: 1.35
```

`options_spec.coffee`:

```
Options = require 'lib/options'

describe "Options", ->

    options = null

    beforeEach ->
        console.log 'in beforeEach'
        console.log options
        console.log Options
        options = new Options()

    it "should not be undefined", ->
        console.log 'in should not be undefined'
        expect(options).not.toBeUndefined()
```

I cannot seem to get the simplest test to run quite yet, it yields the following when I run `cake test`:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.3 server started at http://localhost:9878/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket gHUPisG4Ki3ILcIxxpyl with id 11889221
LOG: 'in beforeEach'
LOG: null
LOG: Object{}
LOG: 'in should not be undefined'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) Options should not be undefined FAILED
    TypeError: '[object Object]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Options()')
        at /Users/kross/alienfast/acme/test/options_spec.js:12
        at /Users/kross/alienfast/acme/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js:117
        at /Users/kross/alienfast/acme/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js:171
        at http://localhost:9878/karma.js:189
        at http://localhost:9878/context.html:45
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.002 secs / 0.002 secs)
Karma has exited with 1
```

The generated `app.js`:

```
(function(/*! Brunch !*/) {
  'use strict';

  var globals = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : global;
  if (typeof globals.require === 'function') return;

  var modules = {};
  var cache = {};

  var has = function(object, name) {
    return ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(object, name);
  };

  var expand = function(root, name) {
    var results = [], parts, part;
    if (/^\.\.?(\/|$)/.test(name)) {
      parts = [root, name].join('/').split('/');
    } else {
      parts = name.split('/');
    }
    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      part = parts[i];
      if (part === '..') {
        results.pop();
      } else if (part !== '.' && part !== '') {
        results.push(part);
      }
    }
    return results.join('/');
  };

  var dirname = function(path) {
    return path.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');
  };

  var localRequire = function(path) {
    return function(name) {
      var dir = dirname(path);
      var absolute = expand(dir, name);
      return globals.require(absolute, path);
    };
  };

  var initModule = function(name, definition) {
    var module = {id: name, exports: {}};
    cache[name] = module;
    definition(module.exports, localRequire(name), module);
    return module.exports;
  };

  var require = function(name, loaderPath) {
    var path = expand(name, '.');
    if (loaderPath == null) loaderPath = '/';

    if (has(cache, path)) return cache[path].exports;
    if (has(modules, path)) return initModule(path, modules[path]);

    var dirIndex = expand(path, './index');
    if (has(cache, dirIndex)) return cache[dirIndex].exports;
    if (has(modules, dirIndex)) return initModule(dirIndex, modules[dirIndex]);

    throw new Error('Cannot find module "' + name + '" from '+ '"' + loaderPath + '"');
  };

  var define = function(bundle, fn) {
    if (typeof bundle === 'object') {
      for (var key in bundle) {
        if (has(bundle, key)) {
          modules[key] = bundle[key];
        }
      }
    } else {
      modules[bundle] = fn;
    }
  };

  var list = function() {
    var result = [];
    for (var item in modules) {
      if (has(modules, item)) {
        result.push(item);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  globals.require = require;
  globals.require.define = define;
  globals.require.register = define;
  globals.require.list = list;
  globals.require.brunch = true;
})();
(function() {
  var WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;
  var br = window.brunch = (window.brunch || {});
  var ar = br['auto-reload'] = (br['auto-reload'] || {});
  if (!WebSocket || ar.disabled) return;

  var cacheBuster = function(url){
    var date = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000).toString();
    url = url.replace(/(\&|\\?)cacheBuster=\d*/, '');
    return url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') +'cacheBuster=' + date;
  };

  var reloaders = {
    page: function(){
      window.location.reload(true);
    },

    stylesheet: function(){
      [].slice
        .call(document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'))
        .filter(function(link){
          return (link != null && link.href != null);
        })
        .forEach(function(link) {
          link.href = cacheBuster(link.href);
        });
    }
  };
  var port = ar.port || 9485;
  var host = br.server || window.location.hostname;

  var connect = function(){
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://' + host + ':' + port);
    connection.onmessage = function(event){
      if (ar.disabled) return;
      var message = event.data;
      var reloader = reloaders[message] || reloaders.page;
      reloader();
    };
    connection.onerror = function(){
      if (connection.readyState) connection.close();
    };
    connection.onclose = function(){
      window.setTimeout(connect, 1000);
    };
  };
  connect();
})();

;require.register("initialize", function(exports, require, module) {
require('lib/helpers');

$(function() {
  return console.log("in initialize");
});
});

;require.register("lib/calendar", function(exports, require, module) {

});

;require.register("lib/helpers", function(exports, require, module) {

});

;require.register("lib/options", function(exports, require, module) {
var Options;

Options = (function() {
  function Options() {}

  Options.prototype.defaults = {
    lang: "en"
  };

  return Options;

})();
});

;/*!

 handlebars v1.3.0

Copyright (C) 2011 by Yehuda Katz

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.

@license
*/
/* exported Handlebars */
var Handlebars = (function() {
// handlebars/safe-string.js
var __module3__ = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__;
  // Build out our basic SafeString type
  function SafeString(string) {
    this.string = string;
  }

  SafeString.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "" + this.string;
  };

  __exports__ = SafeString;
  return __exports__;
})();

// handlebars/utils.js
var __module2__ = (function(__dependency1__) {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__ = {};
  /*jshint -W004 */
  var SafeString = __dependency1__;

  var escape = {
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&#x27;",
    "`": "&#x60;"
  };

  var badChars = /[&<>"'`]/g;
  var possible = /[&<>"'`]/;

  function escapeChar(chr) {
    return escape[chr] || "&amp;";
  }

  function extend(obj, value) {
    for(var key in value) {
      if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(value, key)) {
        obj[key] = value[key];
      }
    }
  }

  __exports__.extend = extend;var toString = Object.prototype.toString;
  __exports__.toString = toString;
  // Sourced from lodash
  // https://github.com/bestiejs/lodash/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
  var isFunction = function(value) {
    return typeof value === 'function';
  };
  // fallback for older versions of Chrome and Safari
  if (isFunction(/x/)) {
    isFunction = function(value) {
      return typeof value === 'function' && toString.call(value) === '[object Function]';
    };
  }
  var isFunction;
  __exports__.isFunction = isFunction;
  var isArray = Array.isArray || function(value) {
    return (value && typeof value === 'object') ? toString.call(value) === '[object Array]' : false;
  };
  __exports__.isArray = isArray;

  function escapeExpression(string) {
    // don't escape SafeStrings, since they're already safe
    if (string instanceof SafeString) {
      return string.toString();
    } else if (!string && string !== 0) {
      return "";
    }

    // Force a string conversion as this will be done by the append regardless and
    // the regex test will do this transparently behind the scenes, causing issues if
    // an object's to string has escaped characters in it.
    string = "" + string;

    if(!possible.test(string)) { return string; }
    return string.replace(badChars, escapeChar);
  }

  __exports__.escapeExpression = escapeExpression;function isEmpty(value) {
    if (!value && value !== 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  __exports__.isEmpty = isEmpty;
  return __exports__;
})(__module3__);

// handlebars/exception.js
var __module4__ = (function() {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__;

  var errorProps = ['description', 'fileName', 'lineNumber', 'message', 'name', 'number', 'stack'];

  function Exception(message, node) {
    var line;
    if (node && node.firstLine) {
      line = node.firstLine;

      message += ' - ' + line + ':' + node.firstColumn;
    }

    var tmp = Error.prototype.constructor.call(this, message);

    // Unfortunately errors are not enumerable in Chrome (at least), so `for prop in tmp` doesn't work.
    for (var idx = 0; idx < errorProps.length; idx++) {
      this[errorProps[idx]] = tmp[errorProps[idx]];
    }

    if (line) {
      this.lineNumber = line;
      this.column = node.firstColumn;
    }
  }

  Exception.prototype = new Error();

  __exports__ = Exception;
  return __exports__;
})();

// handlebars/base.js
var __module1__ = (function(__dependency1__, __dependency2__) {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__ = {};
  var Utils = __dependency1__;
  var Exception = __dependency2__;

  var VERSION = "1.3.0";
  __exports__.VERSION = VERSION;var COMPILER_REVISION = 4;
  __exports__.COMPILER_REVISION = COMPILER_REVISION;
  var REVISION_CHANGES = {
    1: '<= 1.0.rc.2', // 1.0.rc.2 is actually rev2 but doesn't report it
    2: '== 1.0.0-rc.3',
    3: '== 1.0.0-rc.4',
    4: '>= 1.0.0'
  };
  __exports__.REVISION_CHANGES = REVISION_CHANGES;
  var isArray = Utils.isArray,
      isFunction = Utils.isFunction,
      toString = Utils.toString,
      objectType = '[object Object]';

  function HandlebarsEnvironment(helpers, partials) {
    this.helpers = helpers || {};
    this.partials = partials || {};

    registerDefaultHelpers(this);
  }

  __exports__.HandlebarsEnvironment = HandlebarsEnvironment;HandlebarsEnvironment.prototype = {
    constructor: HandlebarsEnvironment,

    logger: logger,
    log: log,

    registerHelper: function(name, fn, inverse) {
      if (toString.call(name) === objectType) {
        if (inverse || fn) { throw new Exception('Arg not supported with multiple helpers'); }
        Utils.extend(this.helpers, name);
      } else {
        if (inverse) { fn.not = inverse; }
        this.helpers[name] = fn;
      }
    },

    registerPartial: function(name, str) {
      if (toString.call(name) === objectType) {
        Utils.extend(this.partials,  name);
      } else {
        this.partials[name] = str;
      }
    }
  };

  function registerDefaultHelpers(instance) {
    instance.registerHelper('helperMissing', function(arg) {
      if(arguments.length === 2) {
        return undefined;
      } else {
        throw new Exception("Missing helper: '" + arg + "'");
      }
    });

    instance.registerHelper('blockHelperMissing', function(context, options) {
      var inverse = options.inverse || function() {}, fn = options.fn;

      if (isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

      if(context === true) {
        return fn(this);
      } else if(context === false || context == null) {
        return inverse(this);
      } else if (isArray(context)) {
        if(context.length > 0) {
          return instance.helpers.each(context, options);
        } else {
          return inverse(this);
        }
      } else {
        return fn(context);
      }
    });

    instance.registerHelper('each', function(context, options) {
      var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
      var i = 0, ret = "", data;

      if (isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

      if (options.data) {
        data = createFrame(options.data);
      }

      if(context && typeof context === 'object') {
        if (isArray(context)) {
          for(var j = context.length; i<j; i++) {
            if (data) {
              data.index = i;
              data.first = (i === 0);
              data.last  = (i === (context.length-1));
            }
            ret = ret + fn(context[i], { data: data });
          }
        } else {
          for(var key in context) {
            if(context.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if(data) { 
                data.key = key; 
                data.index = i;
                data.first = (i === 0);
              }
              ret = ret + fn(context[key], {data: data});
              i++;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      if(i === 0){
        ret = inverse(this);
      }

      return ret;
    });

    instance.registerHelper('if', function(conditional, options) {
      if (isFunction(conditional)) { conditional = conditional.call(this); }

      // Default behavior is to render the positive path if the value is truthy and not empty.
      // The `includeZero` option may be set to treat the condtional as purely not empty based on the
      // behavior of isEmpty. Effectively this determines if 0 is handled by the positive path or negative.
      if ((!options.hash.includeZero && !conditional) || Utils.isEmpty(conditional)) {
        return options.inverse(this);
      } else {
        return options.fn(this);
      }
    });

    instance.registerHelper('unless', function(conditional, options) {
      return instance.helpers['if'].call(this, conditional, {fn: options.inverse, inverse: options.fn, hash: options.hash});
    });

    instance.registerHelper('with', function(context, options) {
      if (isFunction(context)) { context = context.call(this); }

      if (!Utils.isEmpty(context)) return options.fn(context);
    });

    instance.registerHelper('log', function(context, options) {
      var level = options.data && options.data.level != null ? parseInt(options.data.level, 10) : 1;
      instance.log(level, context);
    });
  }

  var logger = {
    methodMap: { 0: 'debug', 1: 'info', 2: 'warn', 3: 'error' },

    // State enum
    DEBUG: 0,
    INFO: 1,
    WARN: 2,
    ERROR: 3,
    level: 3,

    // can be overridden in the host environment
    log: function(level, obj) {
      if (logger.level <= level) {
        var method = logger.methodMap[level];
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined' && console[method]) {
          console[method].call(console, obj);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  __exports__.logger = logger;
  function log(level, obj) { logger.log(level, obj); }

  __exports__.log = log;var createFrame = function(object) {
    var obj = {};
    Utils.extend(obj, object);
    return obj;
  };
  __exports__.createFrame = createFrame;
  return __exports__;
})(__module2__, __module4__);

// handlebars/runtime.js
var __module5__ = (function(__dependency1__, __dependency2__, __dependency3__) {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__ = {};
  var Utils = __dependency1__;
  var Exception = __dependency2__;
  var COMPILER_REVISION = __dependency3__.COMPILER_REVISION;
  var REVISION_CHANGES = __dependency3__.REVISION_CHANGES;

  function checkRevision(compilerInfo) {
    var compilerRevision = compilerInfo && compilerInfo[0] || 1,
        currentRevision = COMPILER_REVISION;

    if (compilerRevision !== currentRevision) {
      if (compilerRevision < currentRevision) {
        var runtimeVersions = REVISION_CHANGES[currentRevision],
            compilerVersions = REVISION_CHANGES[compilerRevision];
        throw new Exception("Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. "+
              "Please update your precompiler to a newer version ("+runtimeVersions+") or downgrade your runtime to an older version ("+compilerVersions+").");
      } else {
        // Use the embedded version info since the runtime doesn't know about this revision yet
        throw new Exception("Template was precompiled with a newer version of Handlebars than the current runtime. "+
              "Please update your runtime to a newer version ("+compilerInfo[1]+").");
      }
    }
  }

  __exports__.checkRevision = checkRevision;// TODO: Remove this line and break up compilePartial

  function template(templateSpec, env) {
    if (!env) {
      throw new Exception("No environment passed to template");
    }

    // Note: Using env.VM references rather than local var references throughout this section to allow
    // for external users to override these as psuedo-supported APIs.
    var invokePartialWrapper = function(partial, name, context, helpers, partials, data) {
      var result = env.VM.invokePartial.apply(this, arguments);
      if (result != null) { return result; }

      if (env.compile) {
        var options = { helpers: helpers, partials: partials, data: data };
        partials[name] = env.compile(partial, { data: data !== undefined }, env);
        return partials[name](context, options);
      } else {
        throw new Exception("The partial " + name + " could not be compiled when running in runtime-only mode");
      }
    };

    // Just add water
    var container = {
      escapeExpression: Utils.escapeExpression,
      invokePartial: invokePartialWrapper,
      programs: [],
      program: function(i, fn, data) {
        var programWrapper = this.programs[i];
        if(data) {
          programWrapper = program(i, fn, data);
        } else if (!programWrapper) {
          programWrapper = this.programs[i] = program(i, fn);
        }
        return programWrapper;
      },
      merge: function(param, common) {
        var ret = param || common;

        if (param && common && (param !== common)) {
          ret = {};
          Utils.extend(ret, common);
          Utils.extend(ret, param);
        }
        return ret;
      },
      programWithDepth: env.VM.programWithDepth,
      noop: env.VM.noop,
      compilerInfo: null
    };

    return function(context, options) {
      options = options || {};
      var namespace = options.partial ? options : env,
          helpers,
          partials;

      if (!options.partial) {
        helpers = options.helpers;
        partials = options.partials;
      }
      var result = templateSpec.call(
            container,
            namespace, context,
            helpers,
            partials,
            options.data);

      if (!options.partial) {
        env.VM.checkRevision(container.compilerInfo);
      }

      return result;
    };
  }

  __exports__.template = template;function programWithDepth(i, fn, data /*, $depth */) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 3);

    var prog = function(context, options) {
      options = options || {};

      return fn.apply(this, [context, options.data || data].concat(args));
    };
    prog.program = i;
    prog.depth = args.length;
    return prog;
  }

  __exports__.programWithDepth = programWithDepth;function program(i, fn, data) {
    var prog = function(context, options) {
      options = options || {};

      return fn(context, options.data || data);
    };
    prog.program = i;
    prog.depth = 0;
    return prog;
  }

  __exports__.program = program;function invokePartial(partial, name, context, helpers, partials, data) {
    var options = { partial: true, helpers: helpers, partials: partials, data: data };

    if(partial === undefined) {
      throw new Exception("The partial " + name + " could not be found");
    } else if(partial instanceof Function) {
      return partial(context, options);
    }
  }

  __exports__.invokePartial = invokePartial;function noop() { return ""; }

  __exports__.noop = noop;
  return __exports__;
})(__module2__, __module4__, __module1__);

// handlebars.runtime.js
var __module0__ = (function(__dependency1__, __dependency2__, __dependency3__, __dependency4__, __dependency5__) {
  "use strict";
  var __exports__;
  /*globals Handlebars: true */
  var base = __dependency1__;

  // Each of these augment the Handlebars object. No need to setup here.
  // (This is done to easily share code between commonjs and browse envs)
  var SafeString = __dependency2__;
  var Exception = __dependency3__;
  var Utils = __dependency4__;
  var runtime = __dependency5__;

  // For compatibility and usage outside of module systems, make the Handlebars object a namespace
  var create = function() {
    var hb = new base.HandlebarsEnvironment();

    Utils.extend(hb, base);
    hb.SafeString = SafeString;
    hb.Exception = Exception;
    hb.Utils = Utils;

    hb.VM = runtime;
    hb.template = function(spec) {
      return runtime.template(spec, hb);
    };

    return hb;
  };

  var Handlebars = create();
  Handlebars.create = create;

  __exports__ = Handlebars;
  return __exports__;
})(__module1__, __module3__, __module4__, __module2__, __module5__);

  return __module0__;
})();

;
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

This is my first go-around with brunch, cake and karma-jasmine, I can't quite get a feel for the problem or where to go from here.  Thoughts/pointers/answers/suggested reading would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, 60 seconds later I happened into the solution perusing a brunch skeleton.  I was missing `module.exports =` in my class definition.

So the full Options class looks like:

```
module.exports = class Options
    constructor: () ->

    # public accessible
    defaults:
        lang: "en"
        aspectRatio: 1.35
```

Nonetheless, pointers and any recommended readings are welcome!